# VB.net chart printing incorrectly

Tags: .net, vb.net, printing, charts

I have a chart in a vb.net project that will not print correctly. It appears in the program as follows.
[In program](http://i62.tinypic.com/2dkli7p.png)

However, when printed to PDF or a printer it appears as follows.
[Printed](http://i60.tinypic.com/52z37m.png)

How can I get the series labels to print as shown in the program?

My print code is provided below:

```
Private Sub cmdPrintResults_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdPrintResults.Click

    printDialogFormUI.Document = printResults
    printResults.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = True
    If printDialogFormUI.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then printResults.Print()

End Sub

Private Sub printResults_PrintPage(sender As Object, e As Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles printResults.PrintPage
    ' Create Rectangle structure, used to set the position of the chart 
    Dim myRec As New System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, 1200, 800)
    chartResults.Printing.PrintPaint(e.Graphics, myRec)

End Sub
```

Thanks for your assistance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by using annotations and anchoring them to the data points instead of adding labels to each data point.